# Flutter how to retrieve javascript value from flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript (addEventListener)

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter code snippet which listens for postMessage from my iframe page. 
(flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.9+1)

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((viewState) async {
    String script = 'window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);' +
            'function receiveMessage(event) {console.log(\'receiving data from child , data as follows: \',event.data)}';
    flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(script);
}
```

I would like to trigger specific flutter functions if **event.data** returns a **specific value** , 
**camera** value would trigger my **specific function** that calls the camera plugin and so on. Meaning to say that my target iFrame will attempt to do a cross-origin communication via **postMessage** method.

For Cordova, I could do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener( "message" , function( event )
{
  else if( event.data.indexOf( "camera" ) >= 0 )
        {
           //Trigger Camera Function
```

How do I go about doing this for flutter?

Comment: How about `flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(script).then((result) {/* Do job*/});`?

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm This would be like a subscribing service, where the postMessage will send more than once, the code should not just run once but await for the right message being sent back.

Comment: I got you idea. Answered this question. I tested it on Android device but not iOS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2 solution for you:

**Solution 1**: Recommend

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

final Set<JavascriptChannel> jsChannels = [
  JavascriptChannel(
      name: 'Print',
      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
        print('message.message: ${message.message}');
      }),
].toSet();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
              url: Uri.dataFromString(
                      '<html><button onclick="Print.postMessage(\'test\');">Click me</button></html>',
                      mimeType: 'text/html')
                  .toString(),
              appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Widget webview")),
              javascriptChannels: jsChannels,
            ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> I/flutter (22119): message.message: test

**Solution 2**: If you want to keep your `window.post`. (Maybe you would like to use the `iframe` from another platform)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

final Set<JavascriptChannel> jsChannels = [
  JavascriptChannel(
      name: 'Print',
      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
        print('message.message: ${message.message}');
      }),
].toSet();

void main() {
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((state) async {
    if (state.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
      String script =
          'window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);' +
              'function receiveMessage(event) {Print.postMessage(event.data);}';
      flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(script);
    }
  });
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
              url: Uri.dataFromString(
                      '<html><button onclick="window.postMessage(\'test\', \'*\');">Click me</button></html>',
                      mimeType: 'text/html')
                  .toString(),
              appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Widget webview")),
              javascriptChannels: jsChannels,
            ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> I/flutter (22119): message.message: test

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_webview_plugin: 0.3.9+1
```

**Reference**:

- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/309
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/pull/457
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/364
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/pull/523/files
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/305

Comment: Ahh thanks, let me get back to you soon once I tried it out. Was about to try on Javascript channels, and looks like it was a right choice!

Comment: @Gene, Did you checked this code? I don't have iOS device so I cant check iOS code.

Comment: @Gene I checked it by iOS today. It's worked. If it also work for you. Please mark my answer as accepted.