# How do I call Javascript code from Dart and register the callback in my console?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, webview

I have a Javascript file that I'm calling in my [Flutter Webview Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus#-readme-tab-).

I am trying to return the callback in the console after the onReward method is called. This is the code of my js file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.theoremreach/v3/theorem_reach.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <iframe src="https://theoremreach.com/respondent_entry/direct?api_key=845783b32b8bef12f1b55a36a8be&user_id=12345"></iframe>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var theoremReachConfig = {
apiKey: "",
userId: "12345",
onRewardCenterOpened: onRewardCenterOpened,
onReward: onReward,
onRewardCenterClosed: onRewardCenterClosed
};

var TR = new TheoremReach(theoremReachConfig);

function onRewardCenterOpened(){
console.log("onRewardCenterOpened");

}

function onReward(data){
console.log("onReward: " + data.earnedThisSession);
}

function onRewardCenterClosed(){
console.log("onRewardCenterClosed");
}

if (TR.isSurveyAvailable()) {
TR.showRewardCenter();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how I'm calling it in my Dart file:

```
...
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Reward earned"), actions: [
         Text("$reward"),
         ]),
        body: WebViewPlus(
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
        controller.loadAsset(
          'assets/tr.html',
        );
      },
    ));
  }
```

When I complete a survey I get the following message in my console:

```
I/chromium( 3560): [INFO:CONSOLE(28)] "onReward: 2", source: http://localhost:56537/assets/tr.html (28)
```

I want to scan this console message and just add the value of the reward, i.e. 2, in my existing page and display it in the appBar.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59024928/5061381) answer.

Comment: is there a way to read the console message for the output? LIke I want to add the console message 'onReward:2' in my dart code @SamiHaddad

Comment: You can send the data using postMessage: `postMessage(data.earnedThisSession)` and read it with onMessageReceived and manipulate it in your dart code.

Comment: How do I read the data with onMessageReceived ?@SamiHaddad

Comment: Check the answer I linked above.

Comment: Is there any other way, without using webview plugin